# Django: Many-to-many relation edit

Tags: django, forms, postgresql

I have a model called Connector that has a foreign key to profile and a many-to-many relation with an ExternalAttribute model.  The ExternalAttribute model has a list of attribute objects that are static.  I want users to be able to add and remove the attributes of the ExternalAttribute model from their profiles.

In the forms, I pull down all the objects from ExternalAttribute into a ModelMultipleChoiceField, which works fine, but I cannot save the selected attributes and add an object to the Connector model.

Here is the form save code:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user = User.objects.get(username=self.cleaned_data['user']))

connector = Connector(profile=profile)
connector.profile = profile
connector.attributes = self.cleaned_data['selected_attributes']
connector.save()
```

When I try to save the selected attributes in the form, I get this error in the stack trace:

```
ValueError: "<Connector: Connector object>" needs to have a value for field "connector" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

I am working with an inefficient database and must use these models.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object must be saved - so that it has primary key - before M2M relationships are saved. Update your code as

```
connector = Connector(profile=profile)
connector.profile = profile
connector.save()
connector.attributes = self.cleaned_data['selected_attributes']
connector.save()
```